# i am not able to change colour of links using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change font colour of links using css.

```css
#mynav a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mynav">
    <li id="us">
      <a href="#name">Orchard Childrens Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#number">01283******</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#twitter"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But changes are not reflected.

Comment: try `.nav>li>a{color:#000}`

Comment: not working either

Comment: Clear your cache mate, control+f5, you code works

Comment: #mynav a{color:black} work perfectly https://www.bootply.com/lh5Q6KQQcp

Comment: What color are they? If the are purple, try #mynav a:visited { #000 } Your Code works for me, all links are black, as expected

Comment: it works clear cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your `cache` using `ctrl+F5` or `shift+F5`. It will re-download cached content *(ie. JavaScript files, images, etc...)*

Answer (score 0):

```css
#mynav a {
  color: #000000!important;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

User above code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works but if you have problems you should try with

```
#mynav a,
#mynav a:link {
//some rules
}
```